# HTML Symbols magic

Tags: html

just realized that html symbols like:

```
&amp;
```

will be also recognized by browser WITHOUT

```
;
```

I had problem because of that:

```
&current
```

was replaced with

```
¤t
```

can you clarify - why?

Comment: Where do you see `&curren` being replace with `¤`? `[no-repro]` Perhaps you actually typed `&curren;t` (rendered as `¤t`) or `&current;` (rendered as `¤t;`).

Comment: @Matt - no, this is standardised behaviour in modern browsers. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Some** named character references are, for backward compatibility reasons, recognised without needing a trailing semicolon. `&curren` is one of them.

A full list of named character references, which shows those that don't need a trailing semicolon is given here: https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/syntax.html#named-character-references

Answer (score 3):

Because any `&` in HTML should be encoded as `&amp;`. So any `&` on its own will be interpreted as the start of a HTML entity and browsers attempt error correction (the parser may attempt to interpret the entity if a character falls outside of its allowable sequence, such as the space character).

Whenever you use a `&` in your HTML, encode it as `&amp;`.

Answer (score 1):

Browsers try hard to make sense of garbage when they can. There's no rule that says they should do this, or that they have to, or even that it's a good idea. But if some browsers do this, then they just do.

Comment: There is a rule. It's in the HTML5 spec.

Comment: ...which is fully supported by every browser in existence?